# How can I pass dynamic path in translate.stream()?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-translate, ngx-translate

I am using `translate.stream()` in `ngx-translate`. It works fine if I pass path under single inverted comma's like: `translate.stream('sectionA.errors.required' , {fieldName: field.templateOptions.label})`.
It won't work if I pass my JSON response under it. like: `translate.stream(this.myJSONresponse.errors.required , {fieldName: field.templateOptions.label})` What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You must provide translation KEY - which is string

in here

```
translate.stream('sectionA.errors.required' , {fieldName: field.templateOptions.label})
```

`sectionA.errors.required` is a key (as a whole)

here

```
translate.stream(this.myJSONresponse.errors.required , {fieldName: field.templateOptions.label})
```

whatever is A VALUE OF `this.myJSONresponse.errors.required` is passed as the message key (boolean maybe?) - equivalent of

```
translate.stream(`${this.myJSONresponse.errors.required}` , {fieldName: field.templateOptions.label})
```

thus those calls are very different while you would expect to be the same

so if
`this.myJSONresponse.errors.required=="sectionA.errors.required"`, then it will work, but most probably it is not your case

Normally backend sends some sort of fixed error codes to indicate what kind of error it is (field.required, date.invalid, value.max.exceeded etc) and on the front you use those codes as translation keys.

Comment: any other way I could do it?

Comment: I am getting the exact value even when I pass the `translate.stream(this.myJSONresponse.errors.required)` but not able to interpolate the  `{fieldName: field.templateOptions.label}`.

Comment: How do I render HTML tags in my JSON via translate.stream() ?? Do I need any other function to do this??

Comment: `this.myJSONresponse.errors.required` you want the message key, not value (of whatever) - that is my point.

Comment: I resolved that with a trick. My next road block is rendering HTML tags under stream or instant function. Thank you for the suggestion tho.